# Ran .NET 4.61 installer, still don't see new framework profile in new project dialog?

Tags: c#, .net

Previously the highest .NET framework profile I had installed with Visual Studio 2013 was 4.5x.  I then downloaded and ran the offline installer for 4.61, found here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49982

After the installation completed successfully (no error reports and nothing in the system event logs), I restarted the system as instructed and reloaded VS2013.  However, I *still* don't see anything higher than 4.5x in the list of available frameworks when I choose *New Project*.  Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

**UPDATE**: I already had installed the 4.6 pack using the same procedure before installing the 4.61 pack.  *Neither 4.6 or 4.61 are showing in the framework choice drop-down when creating a new project.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To develop with .NET 4.6, you'll need to install the [.NET Framework 4.6 Targeting Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48136) after installing the 4.6 framework:

> The .NET Framework 4.6 Targeting Pack is a package that enables developers to build applications targeting the .NET Framework 4.6 using either Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012 or third party IDEs. You need to download and install the .NET Framework 4.6 prior to installing the targeting pack.

With .NET 4.6.1, the framework, targeting pack, language pack and intellisense updates are all bundled together in the [.NET Framework 4.6.1 Developer Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49978).

> The Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Developer Pack is a single package that bundles the .NET Framework 4.6.1, the .NET 4.6.1 Targeting Pack and the .NET 4.6.1 SDK. The corresponding language pack for Dev Pack contains the .NET Framework 4.6.1 language pack, .NET 4.6.1 SDK language pack and the Intellisense files. Developers can use this package to install all the different components for .NET 4.6.1 and build applications targeting the .NET Framework 4.6.1 using either Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012 or third party IDEs.

Comment: I already installed the 4.6 pack before installing the 4.61 pack.  Still no luck.

Comment: @RobertOschler You installed the "targeting pack" or the "framework"? You seem to be using the terms interchangeably when they are two completely different products. One is the framework, one is the gubbins to update VS to be able to use the new framework. You should install the targeting pack ***after*** installing the framework. Once again, both the "framework" ***and*** the "targeting pack" should be installed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, didn't know that.  I'll try that in a few hours.  Out of desperation I decided to run VS2013 Update 5 since I was at Update 4, in the hope that would fix things.  That process is time consuming.  Might want to add that clarification to your answer since I bet others will make that mistake too.

Comment: Can I just run the 4.61 targeting pack?  Or do I have to run the 4.6 pack first?

Comment: @RobertOschler I added another package to my answer that looks like an all-in-one solution.

Comment: Excellent find.  Looking forward to trying it when Update 5 completes (wishing I had an SSD about now!).